# Return Value from Ajax Success Request on custom function

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, return

I have looked, and I can see other issues like this, but I have been unable to make this work. I hope someone can help me.

Here is the code on location.js

```
//*********************** Check if admin *************************
      var CheckAdminStatus = function(uid) {
    var Admin_level = 0;
    $.ajax({
            url: 'fn/ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'switch=IsAdmin&uid='+uid,

        success: function(IsAdmin) {
        //console.log(IsAdmin);

            if(IsAdmin) {
                Admin_level = IsAdmin[0].uid_level;
            }

        adminResult(Admin_level);
        }
    });
```

}   // End of Check if admin
And the caller is on index.php file

```
   CheckAdminStatus(window.uid);
   function adminResult(admin) {
      alert(admin);
   }
```

As per Adil suggestion, but i am not getting any alert, nor any ajax call ?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here?  Your function only takes one parameter but you are passing 2.  What do you expect the alert to show?

Comment: I need the var admin to come over from the function to check if the user is an admin or not.  So admin needs to be either 0 or a number 1 - 10

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is an asynchronous call and ajax call could end before success is fired, you can call a function within success and pass desired value to it.

```
function CheckAdminStatus (uid) {
    var Admin_level = 0;
    $.ajax({
            url: 'fn/ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'switch=IsAdmin&uid='+uid,

        success: function(IsAdmin) {
           YourFunctionToCheckAdmin(Admin_level);
        }
    }); 
}   // End of Check if admin

CheckAdminStatus(window.uid) 

function YourFunctionToCheckAdmin(Admin_level)
{
    alert("Do processing with response here... Admin_level = " + Admin_level);
}
```

Comment: How is that returning the level to the variable on the index.php page ?   Thats what i need ?

Comment: I keep looking at your answer Adil, and just makes no sense.  Why call the function within the ajax for the same function??  would yourfunctionToCheckAdmin be global, and it calls the, and how is it passing it back to admin var on the index.php page ?

Comment: Look you call the CheckAdminStatus which calls ajax function that means it calls php function. The result is returned back to client in the success. Now after you receive result in success you have to do something on client? as you just finished the server call and received response. Calling javascript function YourFunctionToCheckAdmin will allow you to take action on the received response.

Comment: Okay, so when i call the function and send over the user id (window.uid) that function is not able to simply return the result as I have demonstrated above.  I have to create another function on the Index.php file to handle it.    I understand that now bit thank you.  But whats the point in having a return if it does not work?

Comment: I have tried it and updated my code as per your suggestion, but it's not firing?